# Convert list with multiple elements to matrix

Tags: r, dataframe

I have four data frames , each data frame has the same number of records and same columns: it looks like this:

```
    CURRENT  30DPD   60DPD  90DPD
1   0.56     56.67    67.6  57.67
2   0.24     56.78    7.6   24.67
3   0.32     56.11    66    34.67
4..........
```

Now from each `df` I am taking the first row and creating a list, then the second row from each table, the third row from each table and so on.
now trying to convert a large list to matrixes and here is the code I am using:

```
for ( i in 1:3542) {  
   vec1 <- One[i,]
   vec2 <- two[i,]
   vec3 <- Three[i,]
   vec4 <- Four[i,]
   tab[[i]] <- c(vec1,vec2,vec3,vec4)
   final[[i]] <-matrix(unlist(tab[[i]]),nr=4,nc=4)
}
```

In the list, I have 3542 elements and I am getting an error when I use this code.

> Error in final[[i]] <- matrix(unlist(tab[[i]]), nr = 4, nc = 4) :
>   more elements supplied than there are to replace

But if I don't use an index then it works fine but for 3000 elements it would be very time-consuming. Any idea how can I create 3542 seperate matrixes using the list?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What does your list look like?

Comment: can you just give the head of your list so that we can see how we may be of help/

Comment: Ohyambu yes I have updated the question , please let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
s = list(dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4) 
  do.call(Map,c(rbind,lapply(s,function(x)data.frame(t(x)))))
```

Comment: I was hoping for individual matrices, thank you though

Comment: @SUBHRASANKHA what do you mean by individual matrices??

Comment: so I have 3542 rows in each data frame and earlier I was taking the first row from each table and creating a list and then creating a matrix , then second row from each table > list > matrix , then third row from each table ans so on.

Comment: @SUBHRASANKHA That is exactly what this code is doing. If you want to test the code. Just store the first 3 rows form each data as s ie `s=list(dat1[1:3,],dat2[1:3,],dat3[1:3,],dat4[1:3,])` then run the next line and see whether the output is not what you want then let me know

Comment: yes this works like a charm :) Thank you so much and sorry for the confusion :P

Comment: @SUBHRASANKHA you can also do: `s=rbind(dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4);tapply(unlist(s),rep(row(dat1),4),matrix,ncol=4)` then you can decide which works faster for you

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the same number of elements in your list :

```
length(unique(lengths(your_list)) # should be one
```

Then take a look at the classes you have in there, to see if your really can/want to coerce them into a matrix :

```
unique(sapply(your_list, function(x) paste(class(x),collapse= " ")))
```

Then I believe the easiest would be to convert first to `data.frame` then to `matrix` :

```
mat <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(your_list))
```

Comment: I have updated the question as the heads were not clear. The solution you provided is not what I am looking for but thank you so much.